# Sorting OrderedDict using Lambda

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, ordereddictionary

I have to sort an ordered dictionary in python using the sorted method and lambda. I’m sorting it by key, and the keys are strings 
Here is the dictionary code I have:

```
sensors = OrderedDict()
sensors['4213'] = ("STEM Center", 0)
sensors['4201'] = ("Foundations Lab ", 1)
sensors['4204'] = ("CS Lab ", 2)
sensors['4218'] = ("Workshop Room ", 3)
sensors['4205'] = ("Tiled Room ", 4)
sensors['Out'] = ("Outside ", 5)
```

How would I sort it so 4201 is first and then the numbers increase and then the last one is Out?

I tried implementing this, and variations of it, but it doesn’t work, the order of the elements stays the same

```
OrderedDict(sorted(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Variations:

```
-sorted(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
-creating a regular dictionary called sensors and then making a new ordered dictionary using OrderedDict(sorted(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Thank you!

Comment: why `items()` if you just want to sort the keys?

Comment: What's the expected output here? I get `OrderedDict([('4201', ('Foundations Lab ', 1)), ('4204', ('CS Lab ', 2)), ('4205', ('Tiled Room ', 4)), ('4213', ('STEM Center', 0)), ('4218', ('Workshop Room ', 3)), ('Out', ('Outside ', 5))])` which is what you mention. `How would I sort it so 4201 is first and then the numbers increase and then the last one is Out?`

Comment: The code you provide (missing a trailing `)`) works exactly as you describe your expected output.

Comment: `OrderedDict()` returns a new sorted dict — it doesn't sort  the old one in place.

Comment: Or did you mean `{'4213': ('STEM Center', 0), '4201': ('Foundations Lab ', 1), '4204': ('CS Lab ', 2), '4218': ('Workshop Room ', 3), '4205': ('Tiled Room ', 4), 'Out': ('Outside ', 5)}`?

Comment: @mad_ Good point, my teacher had used .items, but now I realize that doesn't make much sense. I just tried the code without the .items() but it still doesn't sort the dictionary

Comment: @a.r.john your initial code works: `OrderedDict(sorted(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])` but you need to save it — it **returns** the new sorted dictionary.

Comment: Which means `out = OrderedDict(sorted(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]) print(out)` and out will contain your sorted dictionary

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The key order in a OrderedDict is equal to insertion order. To sort it, create a new one from scratch in desired order.

```
import collections

# source does not have to be sorted, a regular dict will do
sensors = {}
sensors['4213'] = ("STEM Center", 0)
sensors['4201'] = ("Foundations Lab ", 1)
sensors['4204'] = ("CS Lab ", 2)
sensors['4218'] = ("Workshop Room ", 3)
sensors['4205'] = ("Tiled Room ", 4)
sensors['Out'] = ("Outside ", 5)

sorted_keys = sorted(sensors)     # key=... optional
sorted_sensors = collections.OrderedDict((key, sensors[key]) for key in sorted_keys)
```